# How to convert Dynamic Executable to Static Executable?

Tags: c, linux, arm

How can I convert a pre-built dynamic executable to a static one without recompiling from source? I am using ARMv7 cpu on Linux and I have acess to libraries which are needed by the dynamic executable one . ( I can not use Ermine or Statifier !)

Comment: If you are not allowed to use Ermine, Statifier, or jumpstart , then recompiling looks as only option.

Answer (score 2):

You need the static versions of the libraries you are using, and link them to a compiled version of your program that is prepared for static linking.

So I don't think you can circumvent recompiling.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the `.o` files, then you can simply link them with the static versions of the libraries.

This means it's possible to create a static version without compiling from source but usually, people don't keep the `.o` files so I guess you will have to compile everything from source.